# LINQ Update database sort order against a dynamic list

Tags: .net, linq

I have a database table with a sortOrder column.  I display this list to the user and they use jquery to resort the list, then save it back to the server.

After the reorder the list I get a new list in the correct order of all the IDs in that database table.

I need a good way to update this new sort order to the database.  What I want is to query the database with a custom sort order based off this list of IDs I get back from the user.  I can then step through that list and increment the sort order from 0.

Bonus points for code in VB, although C# is fine too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't store the sort order in the database unless you have a sort order field in the datatable (or an association with a sort order table that stores the original table's field as an FK).  If you have this field then in your linq query do, `OrderBy(x=>x.SortOrder)`

So you have database record projection

```
   public class ObjectFromDb{
        int Id{get;set;}
        int SortOrder{get;set;}
   }
```

When you get the `IQueryable<ObjectFromDb> queryable` and the `int[] newSortOrder` , do this:

```
     var oldSortedList = queryable.OrderBy(x=>x.SortOrder).ToList()
     foreach(var i=0;i<oldSortedList.Count;i++;){
        oldSortedList[i].SortOrder = newSortOrder[i];
     }
     dataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: I want to update the sort order in the database.  I have an array coming in with {5,3,2,6,1}.  This is represents the IDs with the correct sort.  The DB will have the the columns like this (id|sortOrder) {6|1, 5|2, 4|3, 3|4, 1|5, 4|5}